# Issue running TestNG from Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, intellij-idea, testng, bitbucket

When trying to trigger a Selenium test thru Jenkins, I face the following issue:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I do have the testNG jar file in my classpath which is shown below:

My Execute Shell command looks like the following:

```
set classpath="${WORKSPACE}/bin;${WORKSPACE}/lib/*"
chmod a+x ${WORKSPACE}/lib/*.jar
java -cp "${WORKSPACE}/out/production/Test;${WORKSPACE}/lib/*" org.testng.TestNG ${WORKSPACE}/TestNG.xml
```

This project is triggered from Bitbucket and is locally built on IntelliJ.

Any help here, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks you are trying to run on a Linux OS.

On Linux, the classpath separator is `:` and not `;`.

http://daviditnotes.blogspot.fr/2007/12/java-classpath-separator.html

Try:

> set classpath="${WORKSPACE}/bin:${WORKSPACE}/lib/*"
>
> chmod a+x ${WORKSPACE}/lib/*.jar
>
> java -cp "${WORKSPACE}/out/production/Test:${WORKSPACE}/lib/*" org.testng.TestNG ${WORKSPACE}/TestNG.xml